# Under what Wix Burn Conditions are Wix "Burn Built-in Variables" set?

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn

I am trying to detect an install condition in a Wix Bootstrapper (*.wxs) source file.  Wix declares "Burn Built-in Variables" in documentation [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables.html).

My source code looks like this:

```
<util:RegistrySearch
  Id="SearchForMyProduct"
  Variable="MyProductIsInstalled"
  Result="exists"
  Root="HKLM"
  Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\MyProduct" />

<bal:Condition Message="service was found. MyProduct is already installed. Please uninstall and try again">
  (WixBundleAction = 3) AND (MyProductIsInstalled = 0)
</bal:Condition>
```

I do not see in the Burn log that WixBundleAction is set. No matter what value I test WixBundleAction against, (WixBundleAction = 3) is FALSE.  The behavior is the same whether I execute the installer via double-click or from the command-line.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the Variable.  For `WixBundleAction`, the documentation says that it happens when the bundle starts up (based on command line parameters) and during the Plan phase.

```
WixBundleAction - set to the numeric value of BOOTSTRAPPER_ACTION
                  from the command-line and updated
                  during the call to IBootstrapperEngine::Plan().
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this means WixBundleAction can't be used in any conditionals that execute before Plan( ) -- such as ExePackage DetectCondition or MsiPackage InstallCondition -- because Plan( ) sets it.  Thank you, this answer ended hours of frustration on why the conditions didn't work.